# Editing Angular Material's Table Cell Padding

Tags: css, angular, angular-material

When I inspect the element with developer tools it shows zero padding, but when I look a it and mouse over it, it very clearly has padding within the cell. I have no idea where this is coming from, and setting 
`td { padding: 0 !important }` does nothing.

Answer (score 72, accepted):

The perceived padding is being caused by `display: table-cell;` and `vertical-align: inherit;` (which usually is value `middle`) from the default browser/user-agent `<td>` styles in combination with a `height` being set on the `tr.mat-row`. The `<tr>` with CSS class `.mat-row` has a set height by default of `48px`. You can adjust the height or set to `height: auto;` then adjust padding to the `td.mat-cell` as needed. This effectively removes the perceived padding that is visible when inspecting with developer tools. The green padding visualization seen in something like Chrome developer tools when inspecting the `<td>` is how just a middle vertically aligned element with table-cell is displayed in the tools. If you examine the Computer properties of that `<td>` you'll see it has zero padding on all four sides.

```
.mat-row {
  height: auto;
}

.mat-cell {
  padding: 8px 8px 8px 0;
}
```

Here is a [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-dqymkd) showing the `height: auto;` on `tr.mat-row` as well as a custom padding value on `td.mat-cell` in action.

While I'd recommend to avoid changing the `display` property value on `td.mat-cell`, you can change it to something like `inline-block` to see the effects without any adjustments to `height` of `mat-row`.

Comment: This only works for me with `!important` on the padding, as the code for the mat-table is apparently written directly into a `<style>` block.

Comment: @Steve, it would depend on where you put your styles. If you use `styleUrls`, as the example in the answer does, component CSS styles are [encapsulated](https://angular.io/guide/component-styles#view-encapsulation) in the component's view and don't require the !important tag as selectors such as `table[_ngcontent-c6]` are created. If you are using global CSS, you may have to increase specificity or use !important as you mentioned.

Comment: Yes, we are trying to avoid component styles and have a global css file for people using Angular Material (as most of our company uses Bootstrap).

Comment: In Angular Material v15 and later, these class names changed to `mat-mdc-row` and `mat-mdc-cell`.