# How to get gap between <tr> in angular material table

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular, angular-material

[image]

i'm trying achive below table format in mat-table any references to impliment.

Comment: It sounds like you are looking for padding. Some discussion has happened on that https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50709363/editing-angular-materials-table-cell-padding

Comment: Also look at this [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-cjxcgt-wtkfg4) referenced from (stackoverflow)[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53954603/why-am-i-unable-to-apply-a-border-to-an-angular-mat-table-row]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this way:

```
   .mat-row {
     height: auto;
  }

  .mat-cell {
     padding: 6px 6px 6px 0;
  }
```